# How to stop a product from adding to cart in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I am creating an extension for adding a free product Y to cart when adding product X. I don't want to add product Y to cart if the user trying to add product Y itself. Can anyone suggest a solution for me??? (I tried to stop the product from adding to cart, but it is not working). 
Thanks

Comment: What if you make product Y "not visible individually"? If it's only added automatically, you don't need the product page, do you?

Comment: You are right @fschmengler. But product Y is selected by the user in admin side.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand. If you edit the question and explain the process in detail, it could be reopened.